# Software Updater firing blanks, not updating to 20.04 LTS

Tags: updates

I have repeatedly been given the option to update to Ubuntu 20.04 LTS by the *Software Updater*. When I click the "Upgrade..." for it to proceed, the only thing that happens is that the *Software Updater* closes.

[image]

I have tried, from the terminal:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Results, nothing but another puzzling issue that is unrelated, pertaining to JavaFX.

```
phil@UbuntuDesktop:~$ sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages have been kept back:
  libopenjfx-java libopenjfx-jni openjfx
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
phil@UbuntuDestktop:~$
```

Any thoughts on how to proceed, or what might be hanging things up?

Comment: Unrelated, but relevant: You may want to fix or remove  those three 'kept back' packages before release-upgrading anyway. Unresolved dangles like those can break release-upgrades.

Comment: Drilling down a couple links, the message is "Upgrades from 18.04 to 20.04.1 are still disabled as we are working through a few upgrade blockers". So I guess I should just be patient. That update is 3 days old.

Comment: 14 updates in the past 15 days. 3 days old, but not forgotten.

Comment: I haven't a clue on how to fix that "dangle". Am getting nothing when doing searches. The situation with java and javafx is kind of messed up currently, with OpenJDK 1.8 not having JavaFX built in like it is on Windows and with Oracle's Linux Java 8 version. I can't recall if I posted a question on this already. I might not have.